# moment.js and bootstrap-datepicker not respecting a user's timezone

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, momentjs

I have a calendar app where a user picks a date for delivery and pickup. The delivery and pickup need to be done in PST, where the drivers are, but the bootstrap-datepicker uses the timezone of the browser. I've added

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/Los_Angeles");
```

to my `application.js` file, but the problem is that the date I get back from the datepicker is returned in the timezone of the browser (I've set it to BST for the purposes of testing).

```
var pickupDate = moment($('#pickup-date').datepicker("getDate"))
=> Thu Jul 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
_d: Wed Jul 06 2016 17:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
_i: Thu Jul 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
pickupWindows = (
  windowsByDate[pickupDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ")] || {}
).pickupWindows
```

so that when I actually compare the date to the dates in my system, it doesn't work because it's not in PST, as expected. The keys in `windowsByDate` are indexed by PST, so this code doesn't work and returned `undefined`.

One hack would be just to re-parse the date as PST, but that seems to be super hacky. Is there a better way to do this? Either force `bootstrap-datepicker` to assume the dates are in PST, or force the returned date to be in PST?

edit:
Actually, I can't even re-parse the date as PST unless I treat it as a string.

```
deliveryDateInTimeZone = moment($('#delivery-date').datepicker("getDate"))
deliveryDateInPst = moment(deliveryDateInTimeZone.format("YYYY-MM-DD"), "YYYY-MM-DD").tz("America/Los_Angeles")
```

This returns the previous date, because `deliveryDateInTimeZone` gets set to the current time zone, but when I format the date, it treats it as a PST time and goes back 8 hours.

edit2:
This is my new hack to get the timezone.

```
deliveryDate = $('#delivery-date').datepicker("getDate")
deliveryDateInPst = moment(deliveryDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (deliveryDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + deliveryDate.getDate() + " 00:00:00 " + moment().format("ZZ"))
```

Comment: Whenever you are dealing with multiple timezones, you should always save date/time as UTC. Only convert to/from UTC<=>locale at input/display time. This eliminates computation problems.

Comment: @Peter That blanket advice doesn't hold true in all use cases, and doesn't help address this question at all - since this is indeed at the point of input.

Comment: @Waynn - The `Date` object will *always* be in the local time zone. There's no avoiding that.  You have to work purely with `moment` objects and strings instead.  Show us what you're doing with the `moment` object you created.  If you're evaluating `_d`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for the response! Yeah, I'm creating the `moment` object from the date that gets returned from the datepicker. I added the `_d` and `_i` keys, and added some more information to the question. Let me know if this helps clarify?

Comment: Read https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/

Comment: Thanks for the link! It helps clarify the behavior of `moment` but doesn't quite work for my issue. Added an edit with something else I tried as well after I read the last suggestion on your post.

Comment: Have you already tried using getUTCDate first and then converting to PST?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that when you get the date from the datepicker, it's already in the timezone of the client, so even if you get the UTC date it doesn't help. I've basically had to do this:

deliveryDate = $('#delivery-date').datepicker("getDate")
deliveryDateInPst = moment(deliveryDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (deliveryDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + deliveryDate.getDate() + " 00:00:00 " + moment().format("ZZ"))

Comment: @WaynnLue did you find a better way to do this.

Comment: @rahul unfortunately, not better than the answer in my edit

Answer (score 0):

In regard to edit 2, rather than extracting values from a Date, creating a string then parsing it with the *moment.js* constructor, consider passing the values from the *Date* directly to the *moment.js* constructor in an array and set the location you want at the same time.

It's virtually the same thing as creating a string then parsing, just more direct. It also avoids messing around with the default timezone.

E.g.:

```js
// Date as if from date picker, i.e. local time set to 00:00:00
let d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log('Initial Date as local: ' + myFormat(d));

// Get browser default timezone (not necessarily perfect)
let localTz = moment.tz.guess();
console.log('Local IANA location  : ' + localTz);

// Use values from Date as America/Los_Angeles (or whatever loc suits)
// Year, month, day, etc. are same value but timezone is different
let dLA = moment.tz(getParts(d), "America/Los_Angeles");
console.log('As Los Angeles date  : ' + dLA.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z"));

// Equivalent local date: create a new moment from dLA using local tz
let dLocal = moment(dLA).tz(localTz);
console.log('Equivalent local date: ' + dLocal.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z"))

// Helpers
// Format Date
function myFormat(d) {
  return d.toLocaleString('en-ca', {
    year: 'numeric', month:'2-digit', day:'2-digit', hour:'2-digit', minute:'2-digit',
    second:'2-digit', hour12: false, timeZoneName:'long'
  }).replace(',','');
}
// Get [year, month, day, etc.] as array
function getParts(d) {
  return [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(),
          d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds(), d.getMilliseconds()];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

See the [*moment.tz* documentation in regard to *tz.guess*](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/).