# Moment js time zone date conversion issue

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using moment js to convert user system time to user specified time zone as per his preference. User system time zone is IST and he is specifing a different time zone. For setting the same I am using

```
moment.tz.setDefault("Pacific/Pago_Pago");
```

But in one of the scenario I am getting different dates. If I do

`moment().startOf('day')`

I am getting today's date as **Thu Oct 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**, But if I am doing

```
moment(endDate).startOf('day')
```

I am getting **Thu Oct 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** Where end date is the result of last statement i.e. **Thu Oct 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

What I am doing wrong here.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/

Answer (score 0):

The timezone used when a moment object is created stays as part of the object and is used for subsequent processing. The effect described will happen if the default timezone is changed after the initial moment object is created.

E.g.

```js
// Set default to IST (+5:30)
moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Kolkata');

// Create initial moment using default timezone
let start = moment().startOf('day');

// Changing the default here doesn't affect above moment
moment.tz.setDefault('Pacific/Pago_Pago');

// This still uses the initial +5:30 offset, not -11:00 for Pago Pago
let timestamp = start.toString();

// This uses the timestamp for the original timezone, but
// then gets start of day in new default timezone
let end = moment(timestamp).startOf('day');

console.log( `Start: ${start.toString()}\nEnd  : ${end.toString()}` );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

Comment: The issue what I am facing here, I am using converted timezone date to date control. Later user can change the date using date control, but when I am reading date back from date control, it is loosing timezone setting and give system timezone again, I am looking for a way to retain timezone setting, in this case Pago Pago

Comment: I am having the same issue mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903594/moment-js-and-bootstrap-datepicker-not-respecting-a-users-timezone
Is there any better way to fix this.

Comment: @rahul—if you want to use dates only, i.e. no time component, then don't use Date objects. Dates don't (or shouldn't) have a timezone. It was a serious error for ECMAScript to parse date–only strings (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd formatted dates) as UTC because it's not consistent with ISO 8601 or common sense. How you fix your issue depends on the use case. If you have a moment object with a particular timezone, then convert to string to use as the value for a form control, then get back another string, then you have to remember the initial timezone and reapply it.

Comment: @rahul—the issue at your link is best solved by using UTC for everything and only using timezones for presentation. If using multiple timezones, then show the user the date, time **and timezone** of dates and times so they know what's going on.